# chef-solo error Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - solo.rb

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, chef-infra

I'm trying to install nginx via the opscode cookbook on Ubuntu 12.04 server. I know it depends on ohai so I have that cookbook downloaded as well. When I run

```
$ sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb
```

i get an error saying

```
FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - solo.rb
```

Not sure how solo.rb is missing when it's in my current directory.

```
$ ls
cache  cookbooks  node.json  node.json~  solo.rb  solo.rb~
```

Here is the output from debug

```
$ sudo chef-solo -l debug -c solo.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.10 ***
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Building node object for vagrant-ubuntu-precise
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Extracting run list from JSON attributes provided on command line
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[ohai]", "recipe[main]", "recipe[nginx]"] from JSON
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Applying attributes from json file
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Platform is ubuntu version 12.04
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Run List is [recipe[ohai], recipe[main], recipe[nginx]]
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Run List expands to [ohai, main, nginx]
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant-ubuntu-precise
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Running start handlers
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: No chefignore file found at /var/chef/cookbooks/chefignore no files will be ignored
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's library file: /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/libraries/manage_node.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's providers from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/job.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/job.rb into a provider named chef-jenkins_job defined in Chef::Provider::ChefJenkinsJob
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's providers from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/execute.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/execute.rb into a provider named chef-jenkins_execute defined in Chef::Provider::ChefJenkinsExecute
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's providers from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/node.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/node.rb into a provider named chef-jenkins_node defined in Chef::Provider::ChefJenkinsNode
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's providers from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/cli.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/providers/cli.rb into a provider named chef-jenkins_cli defined in Chef::Provider::ChefJenkinsCli
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's resources from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/job.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/job.rb into a resource named chef-jenkins_job defined in Chef::Resource::ChefJenkinsJob
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's resources from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/node.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/node.rb into a resource named chef-jenkins_node defined in Chef::Resource::ChefJenkinsNode
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's resources from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/execute.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/execute.rb into a resource named chef-jenkins_execute defined in Chef::Resource::ChefJenkinsExecute
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook chef-jenkins's resources from /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/cli.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/resources/cli.rb into a resource named chef-jenkins_cli defined in Chef::Resource::ChefJenkinsCli
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Node vagrant-ubuntu-precise loading cookbook nginx's attribute file /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx/attributes/default.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Node vagrant-ubuntu-precise loading cookbook nginx's attribute file /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx/attributes/geoip.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Node vagrant-ubuntu-precise loading cookbook nginx's attribute file /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx/attributes/source.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Node vagrant-ubuntu-precise loading cookbook nginx's attribute file /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx/attributes/upload_progress.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Node vagrant-ubuntu-precise loading cookbook ohai's attribute file /var/chef/cookbooks/ohai/attributes/default.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Node vagrant-ubuntu-precise loading cookbook chef-jenkins's attribute file /var/chef/cookbooks/chef-jenkins/attributes/default.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading cookbook nginx's definitions from /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx/definitions/nginx_site.rb
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Loading Recipe ohai via include_recipe
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Found recipe default in cookbook ohai
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: ohai plugins will be at: /etc/chef/ohai_plugins
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Platform ubuntu not found, using all defaults. (Unsupported platform?)
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Processing remote_directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] action create (ohai::default line 23)
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] INFO: Processing cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README] action create (dynamically defined)
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Platform ubuntu not found, using all defaults. (Unsupported platform?)
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - solo.rb
/var/chef/cookbooks/ohai/recipes/default.rb:41:in `read'
/var/chef/cookbooks/ohai/recipes/default.rb:41:in `from_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:578:in `load_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:46:in `load_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:33:in `include_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `include_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:72:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:69:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:69:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:199:in `setup_run_context'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:162:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:207:in `run_application'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:195:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:195:in `run_application'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/chef-solo:25
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo:19
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] DEBUG: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - solo.rb
/var/chef/cookbooks/ohai/recipes/default.rb:41:in `read'
/var/chef/cookbooks/ohai/recipes/default.rb:41:in `from_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:578:in `load_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:46:in `load_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:33:in `include_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `include_recipe'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:72:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:69:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:69:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:199:in `setup_run_context'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:162:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:207:in `run_application'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:195:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:195:in `run_application'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/chef-solo:25
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo:19
[Sun, 20 May 2012 14:00:10 -0400] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - solo.rb
```

Comment: try ./solo.rb instead or full way like /home/ubuntu/solo.rb.

Comment: Tried and it didn't work. I got the exact same output.

Comment: No idea. Try `sudo su -` and then your `chief-solo` command without sudo.

Comment: That didn't work either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to the way chef works. It changes directory to / to avoid any kind of permissions issues, but this means plugins that need access to command line arguments won't know how to get to your relative paths any more.

There is a bug filed with the chef code to address the issue.

For now, using full paths for your `chef-solo` arguments fixes the problems. E.g.

```
$ chef-solo -c /full/path/to/solo.rb -j /full/path/to/node.json -l debug
```

Or as someone else pointed out, removing the `/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README` file will also "fix" the problem. Although not in a real way, since all that is doing is triggering a modification time update on the ohai_plugins folder, triggering chef to reload everything. That functionality is not guaranteed and may break before the aforementioned bug is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug with chef-solo and chef-client, I did some digging and opened a bug here: http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1490?focusedCommentId=25572#comment-25572

Like has already been suggested the workaround is to use the absolute path to the config, any relative path has the same problem.  This also happens whenever the ohai recipe is run without changing any plugins, it's not specific to the nginx cookbook.

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely is "/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README" which get recreated with each run. You just need to delete it before running chef-solo.

Answer (score 0):

If chef-solo 0.10.10 couldn't find your `solo.rb` it will complain with the following message at the start of your debug log:

```
$ chef-solo -c solo.rb -l debug
[2012-06-18T23:27:32+03:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2012-06-18T23:27:32+03:00] WARN: Did not find config file: solo.rb, using command line options.
[2012-06-18T23:27:32+03:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2012-06-18T23:27:32+03:00] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.10 ***
...
```

So the bug is in the logic of recipes that use this config filename somehow.